# IE8 Not Opening Web Pages in New Window

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I've seen this issue on a few random installs of IE8 and can't track it down for the life of me.  If you open a new window by using the traditional <a href="fu" target="_blank">bar</a> - IE8 does absolutely nothing when its clicked on.  I've dug around google for quite some time, to no avail.  Has anyone else experienced this and perhaps has a work-around?

Comment: If you post a tiny, but complete html example, we can try to reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this behavior has stopped occurring with recent releases of IE8.  I think it must have been some sort of security setting that got changed with the later releases of IE8.  Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the pop-up blocker settings have been changed to "High: block all pop-ups".  Check in Tools->Internet Options->Privacy->[Pop-up Blocker] Settings.

Comment: Even when set to the highest level, the pop-up blocker does not interfere with <a ... target="_blank"> links when the user clicks on them since it is a user initiated action.

Comment: This wss with a fresh install with no special settings.  I've hypothesized that it was an issue with an early IE8 beta.